# Short story with a helmet that fits a guys face

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I was 14 when I picked up a book from my school library which contained excerpts and short stories related to space travel and such.

There was this particular story, the first one actually, where a guy finds a white helmet sort of thing which he pulls over his head and it transforms to fit his face and becomes invisible.

The helmet is an alien artifact and is placed on earth so that a native finds it. It collects all kinds of data while the user is wearing it, and gives the wearer super strength and super intelligence.

In the end the guy gets ready to leave earth so that he can transport the data of the helmet to its source community.

Comment: If you have not already, please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see what questions you can answer from there. Like, when were you 14? Where did you go to school? Were there pictures?

Comment: I have read this story - the first guy to don the helmet was a sort of a metal-smith, wasn't he? I somehow associate this story with a well-known author (Pohl? Anderson?) and was almost sure it was in one of Amazon's Science Fiction Megapacks, but was unable to narrow it down.

Answer (score -2):

Almost certainly not it, but it reminds me of the first of the Lucky Starr short juvenile novels by Isaac Asimov, writing as Paul French. The first book in the series was called Space Ranger, I think, and it introduced the mask, but that was set on Mars, not Earth. As I recall it didn't give him super powers but it did protect him from a dust storm.

Even though I don't think this is the answer, I present it for elimination as someone mentioned Asimov.

Comment: I doubt it.  Lucky Starr receives a flexible, scarf like  thing from Martians, on Mars. It does mold itself to his face, but it doesn't give him super powers.  It is a shield that can protect him from certain things, but not from everything.  The weak points of the mask often form a part of the plot.  He also does not have to take it back to the Martians.

Comment: @JRE I remember this.  The "glitter shield" was the internal name for the device.  Absorbs kinetic energy, but won't stop air passing (for instance).  "Why didn't you use the glitter shield" from Bigman always led to exposition of why it wouldn't have helped in a certain fix.